# Proving a Certain Language is Regular

Tags: regex, regular-language

In my computational theory class we have been asked to prove that a certain language is regular:

`Ln` = { `a^(2k+1)` | k is a multiple of n } c { a } *

I'm unsure where to start, usually you would use one of an NFA, DFA, regular expression, or regular grammar. If anyone could help push me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if this is an appropriate question for this site (since it's not directly related to a programming problem) but I'll leave that for others to decide. What I can say is that you should do some formatting work to make your definition a little more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints to get you started:

1. Notice that L<sub>n</sub> = { a<sup>2nr + 1</sup> | r ∈ N }, which you can rewrite as { (a<sup>2n</sup>)<sup>r</sup>a | r ∈ N }. That might expose a bit more structure that you previously noticed.
2. If you want to go down the DFA route, think about what information you need to keep track of at each point in time. Each state in the DFA should tell you something about the string you've seen so far. It might help to notice that it doesn't really matter how many total characters are in the string, just what the remainder is modulo n.
3. If you want to go down the regex route, how would you express the idea of "any number of copies of a<sup>2n</sup> followed by another a?"